# Is it possible to highlight commandlinks in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to highlight commandlinks that have been clicked by setting their background to a new image.
Only the currently selected link should be highlighted and all other links should be at their default state.
Clicking on a link causes a navigation to a new webpage, but the user still sees the links and can use them for navigation.

How do I highlight the currently selected link, so it stays highlighted, until the user clicks another link?

I tried many diffrent ways, by trying to set a new styleClass when an "onclick"-Event has been fired etc. 
I am out of ideas, hope you guys can help me.

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Comment: How is setting a class on click not working for you? Was the class applied to the correct element? Was the CSS rule you created invoked? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @Jasper de Vries Sry for the late response. I solved the problem by toggling through the styleClasses bean side. Now everything works fine!

Comment: In that case please post your solution as an answer and accept it. It might help others.